# A question from Spivak text

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am having trouble understanding the following argument from Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds:

[image]

> The above argument is clear.
>
> **But I cannot figure out how for any fixed $k,$ $$\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{|\sin(a+h)-\sin a-(\cos a).h|}{|(h,k)|}=0$$ implies that $$\lim_{(h,k)\to0}\dfrac{|\sin(a+h)-\sin a-(\cos a).h|}{|(h,k)|}=0.$$ Please help!**

*Added:* Please see if it is correct: for $\epsilon>0~\exists~\delta>0$ such that $\frac{|\sin(a+h)−\sin(a)−\cos(a)h|}{|(h,k)|}<\epsilon$ for $|h|<\delta$ ($k$ is fixed). Then $|(h,k)|<\delta\implies|h|<\delta\implies\frac{|\sin(a+h)−\sin(a)−\cos(a)h|}{|(h,k)|}<\epsilon.$

Comment: $(h,k)\to 0$ $\Rightarrow$ $h\to 0$.

Comment: When you go from the last but one step to the last step in Spivak's argument you notice that convergence holds uniformly over $k$. You get teh desired conclusion because of this uniformity.

Comment: 1.) please replace the Picture by text/Latex. 2.) He already stated in the text: "Since |(h,k)|>=|h| ..."

Comment: Please see if it is correct: for $\epsilon>0~\exists~\delta>0$ such that $\frac{|\sin(a+h)−\sin(a)−\cos(a)h|}{|(h,k)|}<\epsilon$ for $|h|<\delta$ ($k$ is fixed). Then $|(h,k)|<\delta\implies|h|<\delta\implies\frac{|\sin(a+h)−\sin(a)−\cos(a)h|}{|(h,k)|}<\epsilon.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $|(h,k)|\ge |h|$, then
$$
0\le\left|\frac{f(h)}{(h,k)}\right|=\left|\frac{f(h)}{h}\frac{h}{(h,k)}\right|\le \left|\frac{f(h)}{h}\right|.
$$
Now $(h,k)\to 0$ $\Rightarrow$ $h\to 0$. What can you say about the limit?

Answer (score 0):

What is in the numerator is always of the order of $h^2$, :
$$\sin(a+h)-\sin(a)-\cos(a)h=\mathcal{O}(h^2)$$
 while $|(h,k)|$ is at least $|(h,k)|=\mathcal{O}(h)$ if $k\sim h$.

I am not sure if it answers your question. Tell me otherwise.